# why no auxiliary in "you haven't a hope"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Why no auxiliary is used in the phrase "you haven't a hope"?

I've heard "don't have" and "haven't got" patterns only. Have never come across this one.

Comment: I think it might be a difference in dialects.  US English would tend to use "I **don't have** a clue**" or "I **haven't got** a clue", whereas (I think) Commonwealth English is likely to use "I haven't a clue".  But I will let a Commonwealth speaker address this.

Comment: In "You haven't a hope", "have" is an auxiliary verb, while in "You don't have a hope" it's a lexical verb. The clue is that the lexical verb requires _do_-support in negatives and questions, whereas the auxiliary doesn't.

Comment: @BillJ: Seems like you're backing into that analysis. *He  hasn't a hope in hell!*

Comment: @stangdon Auxiliary stative *have* in BrE is mostly used by older speakers, and sounds somewhat formal or old-fashioned.

Comment: **He hasn't a pot to piss in** can still be heard in areas of the US which have had a large population of Irish descent since the mid 1800's.  What makes the verb *auxiliary* there?

Comment: *Hurry, we haven't a moment to lose...*

Comment: @BillJ "You haven't a hope" does *not* have "have" as an auxilary verb. It's a regular lexical verb and still has the literal standard meaning of possession.

Comment: @eques Clearly false, since *-n't* attaches only to auxiliaries.  Consider also inversion.

Comment: @snailplane umm.. no that's not the definition of auxiliary verb. That's a descriptive rule, but doesn't define the essential quality of auxiliary vs lexical verb. An auxiliary verb provides grammatical semantics (like tense or aspect) as opposed to being the principal action. In the sentence "I haven't a hope" have means "to possess" just as it does in "I have a cat". Furthermore an auxiliary verb ordinarily takes another regular verb as a complement.

Comment: When "have" occurs in clauses describing states, expressing such meanings as possession, it can behave as either  a lexical verb or, in some varieties, an auxiliary. The fact that it does not require _do_-support marks it as an auxiliary. By contrast, lexical "have", like any other lexical verb, requires _do_- support ln non-affirmative clauses. Further, auxiliaries have negative inflectional, _n't_  forms whereas no lexical verb does.

Comment: And there's no rule that says a clause must have a lexical verb. "Be" qualifies as an auxiliary verb not just when it is marking progressive aspect or passive voice, but also when it is the only verb in the clause, taking a complement with the form of an AdjP, NP etc.

Comment: Auxiliary verbs are those with the NICE properties, not verbs that “help” other verbs. The acronym NICE stands for negation, inversion, code, and emphasis. Consider the first two. Negation: this is a property of auxiliary, not lexical, verbs, thus auxiliary "He **has** not seen it" is fine, but not lexical *"He **saw** not it". And with Inversion: the auxiliary "**Has** he seen it?" is fine, but not lexical *"**Saw** he it?" The evidence that “have” can be an auxiliary verb or a lexical verb is overwhelming.

Comment: Have can be auxiliary, certainly, but that doesn't mean this use is one. " not verbs that 'help' other verbs" Consider that "auxiliary" literally means helping, thus it achieves some other purpose (like acts as a copula or works with a verb). You are defining something by its use rather than what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that in standard use we would expect an auxiliary verb here (most likely the verb "do")

> You *don't* have (a) hope

would be the standard way to state that idea.

But depending on dialect and circumstance (especially colloquial/conversational ones), some of those standard rules are not always followed. Thus in this case, there is no auxiliary verb. You should not ordinarily imitate this pattern, but should be able to recognize it when it happens.

Note: an [Auxilary Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) is a verb that adds functional or grammatical meaning to the clause in which it appears (especially tense, aspect or modality).

In Modern English, regular verbs ordinarily must have some auxiliary verb for questions and negation, so an auxiliary do (called [Do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)) is required for questions and negations when there is no other auxilary. Other auxiliaries like *have*, *will*, or *be* are common; these indicate various tense or aspect possibilities. Verbs like *can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, etc also work as auxiliaries and specifically indicate "modality" (things like obligation, permission)